# Schwinn meridian three-wheel bicycle

Tags: brakes, pads

Should I rotate the back left or right tire to the front tire.  The front brakes are locking up on the front tire.  I have also loosened the brakes on both sides as much as possible too.  Could rotating the left or right back tire to the front tire solve the front brakes from rubbing on the rim.

Comment: If your front brake is locking up then swapping tyres won't help at all, the brake needs adjusting.

Comment: Can you please add a photo or two of what's going on with your bike ?

Answer (score 3):

Note that you cannot swap wheels, since the front wheel has a different hub from the rear ones.  You could presumably swap tires, but there would be little point in this unless the front tire for some reason has a much thicker tread than the rear ones.

If the brakes are rubbing on the rim it may be that the rim is warped and needs to be "trued", or it may be that the brakes are out of adjustment somehow.  (Rim brakes can be tricky to adjust.)  It's also possible that the axle is simply not seated squarely in the notches of the fork.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Things to check

1. Are your rims bent?  Lift the bike and spin each wheel in turn by hand.  It should not have much of a wobble left and right.  If it does, then the wheel needs "truing"
2. Are your tyres too big?  Were they recently replaced with wider ones?  This can cause brake rub
3. Are your brakes loose in any way?  Its not impossible for a brake pad/holder to move a little even when its clamped down tight.  If the pad touches the tyre at any time then that's bad.
4. The brake pad/blocks wear down over time which gives more space between rim and brake pad.  There's normally a barrel adjuster on the brake lever, and sometimes on the brake itself to adjust the resting position for wear.